# Running Samsung TV Apps SDK 3.5.2 on Boot Camp - The OS became unstable

Tags: samsung-smart-tv, smart-tv

I'm using a MacBook Air with bootcamp and Windows 7 Professional installed.
When trying to to launch Samsung TV Apps SDK(IDE) 3.5.2 Windows crashes after few minutes with a bad blue page.

It looks like Samsung TV SDK attempts to write something to my Mac HD and fails operations.

I would like to know if you have the same issue and your work around.

Comment: Quick note, I face this issue only on BOOTCAMP on Mac, no problems on PC.

Answer (score 1):

After digging the problem I found out a solution:

I **renamed** the file

```
C:\windows\system32\drivers\AppleMNT.sys
```

to

C:\windows\system32\drivers\AppleMNT.sys.bak

This resolved the issue in my case,

I had also to install “vcredist_x86.exe” from “Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Service Pack 1 Redistributable Package ATL Security Update” as it is also required in SDK 3.5.2

If you have other solutions please let me know.